# C# - MemoryStream, image.Save in a loop - random protected memory error

Tags: c#, access-violation, memorystream

While grabbing images (**Image** type) to convert them into "Base64 **String**" in a kind of loop, im always getting this error at a random time of the execution.

> "Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

```
        private void doCapture()
        {
            CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();
        }

        void CaptureInfo_FrameCaptureComplete(PictureBox Frame)
        {
            string str = toB64img(Frame.Image);
            //do something with the string
            this.doCapture();
        }

        private string toB64img(Image image)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);   <==== error HERE
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
```

Image come from directx.capture, webcam capture. (working fine)
I assume that's because something is still in access and wasn't closed yet, so error cause already in use. But how can i fix this issue please?

Comment: The pattern of Disposing of the passed in image is not great as you don't know what else may be trying to use it.

Comment: i added that .dipose() while trying to get ride of the error. Didn't work . im editing to remove that now, so we keep concentrate on the real error so ^^ thanks

Comment: I think you are going to need to shed a bit more light on where the image is coming from for us to help.

Comment: It look like a threading problem. Where image comes from? Please provide a code.

Comment: The cause of the error is most likely not in the code you posted. I'd guess that the image has been corrupted before this code gets called. Do you have any unsafe code in your application?

Comment: `Image` is a fairly thin wrapper around GDI objects. An access violation while manipulating those can come from any number of causes. The problem is in some interaction with unmanaged code, but that's nearly impossible to diagnose if you're not sitting in front of the machine. If you are, you can break out WinDbg and read up on debugging unmanaged code -- but that will take a while.

Comment: I think what this cryptic message is trying to tell you is that the image data in that image is illegal and cannot possibly be saved as a png.

The only reason I can think of for this is a 0x0 image or similar.

Inspect the properties of this image in the debugger.

Comment: Tested some things, all images (even the "maybe faulty" one) have same rawFormat, same size(height,width) etc. [ImageFormat: b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]. So i guess the images are fine since all things are the same for working ones AND the crashing one. I guess thats really about something about writting/accessing to a memory that isn't closed and freed yet. Exact error again in the Debug, on `ìmage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);` is `A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was right in my though.
Something wasn't freed fast enought.
Adding a force GC check right before the RETURN of the function, worked like a charm.. strange.

```
private string toB64img(Image image)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);   
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            GC.Collect();                       <======
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();      <======
            GC.Collect();                       <======
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

``

Comment: may i understand why someone just neg reped me... i found a solution i could't find anywhere on the web yet, shared it incase someone else experience the same another day. i dont think it is a bad move much "lol"